# Java, Jtable setmodel "boolean"

Tags: java, swing, jtable, boolean

I'm making a jtable of products in production.
I have a boolean for ended or !ended.

This boolean should be the key to sort of which products i wish to see in my table.

It should sort all ended away.

But i'm in lack of seeing how to do this.. ;-(

This is how my normal setmodel is working.

My boolean- `poObject.isEnded()` - is what i thought could be implementet in this, for sorting my ProductOrders.

I tried making a new for-loop with the boolean in mind, but all i get, is a null-pointer, not even a sinlge input to my jtable.

```
private void poTabPressed()
    {
        try
        {
            poModel = new TblPOModel(pManager.getAllPOs());
            tblPO.setModel(poModel);
            tblPO.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(125);
            for (int i = 0; i < tblPO.getColumnCount(); i++)
            {
                tblPO.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setResizable(false);
            }
            rightAlignPOTab();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println("ERROR - " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), btw Oracles JTable tutorial contains excelent description about

Comment: If you want to filter in your `JTable`, you could simply set a `RowSorter` (see `JTable#setRowSorter`). This makes it easy to toggle the state of that boolean and show the other entries without having to create new `TableModel` instances

Comment: Hello Robin
Will the sorter leave the true boolean out of the table, so only !true boolean will show ? - I'm asking, because I'm not sure if that is what you mean in your answer. the boolean is not visible in the jtable, it's a difinition in my database.

Comment: See also [*How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: Good example, trashgod.
It's just like my table.
I would like to "not" show the vegetarians ;-)
But i can't see a sorting method for this kind of filtering...